# Replicate deployed and running java web application to multiple hosts

Tags: java, docker, deployment, web-deployment

I have a case where I need to deploy WAR file to multiple hosts. these hosts use Debian OS and have the same structure.

Usually, the site on one host took about 1H to start, this is due to caching which took long time till complete.

So when we have 12 hosts, this means that we need 12H to deploy the site on all hosts.

My question here is about how to deploy and start the site on one host then replicate or copy it to the other hosts, this approach will reduce the time from 12H to 1H.

I read about Docker and if it could help in that, but as I understand. it serves just the host that being running on it, so I cannot distribute the image to other hosts.

Appreciate your help and thanks in advance,

Comment: Why deploy sequentially, one at a time?  Why not deploy concurrently, all at once?

Comment: @AndrewS, deploying all the hosts at same time will cause downtime, so that we need to deploy one by one to keep the site up

Comment: If there is no maintenance window then it must be a 24/7 mission critical app which suggests it deserves mission critical architecture.  Yes, I'm being flippant.  But seriously, how long would it take to recover if all of the hosts went down?  How are security patches applied?  How many hours is leadership willing to waste attempting to apply band-aids before funding is provided to re-architect the app?  I fully recognize these are not easy conversations.  Good luck.